# How can I overload method with ExpandoObject?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, dynamic, expandoobject

I have the following expando object

```
 dynamic person = new ExpandoObject();
        person.FirstName = " FirstName ";
        person.SecondName = " FirstName ";
        person.FullName = person.FirstName + person.SecondName;
        person.BirthDate = new DateTime(1990, 1, 1);

        person.CalcAge = (Func<int>)
            (() => DateTime.Now.Year - person.BirthDate.Year);
```

I define **`CalcAge`** method to calculate age .. I want to add overloaded method that have a parameter like the below

```
person.CalcAge = (Func<DateTime, int>)
            ((DateTime date) => date.Year - person.BirthDate.Year);
```

How can I implement it with **`ExpandoObject`** in which I can do the below ?

```
int age1 = person.CalcAge();
MessageBox.Show(age1.ToString());

int age2 = person.CalcAge2(new DateTime(1980, 1, 1));
MessageBox.Show(age2.ToString());
```

Comment: In future, please add code as *text* rather than screenshots.

Comment: @Jon I did it now .. thanks

Comment: The calculation for `CalcAge` is wrong :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can. I'd strongly suggest you create a new *named* type instead. It looks like you know all the properties and methods you want to create - so just create a `Person` type. `ExpandoObject` is useful in some scenarios, but don't expect it to be able to cope with everything.

If you really want a dynamic object with this functionality, you'll need to derive a class from `DynamicObject` instead - that way you *could* implement overloading, if you wanted to (by intercepting method invocations).

Comment: Jon Skeet ! I know this is an old post by i hope you see this :-) are you maybe aware of a library that has something like ExpandoObject and allows overloaded methods? If I implement this myself how should i approach implementing the method resolution (Assuming i want to mimic C#'s behavior)? Thank you.

Comment: @AK_: No, I don't know of anything, I'm afraid. Implementing the C# overloading rules would be *hard* - there's a lot of complicated stuff there.